# Unity3D: Отклонить вектор на N градусов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется некоторый единичный вектор, который представляет собой координату в сферическом пространстве. Необходимо получить из него 4 вектора отклонённых в разные стороны(вправо, влево, вперёд, назад) на определённое количество градусов. Для этих действий я использую следующий код:

```
Vector3 center = point;
Vector3 left = Quaternion.Euler(-30, 0, 0) * center;
Vector3 right = Quaternion.Euler(30, 0, 0) * center;
Vector3 back = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -30) * center;
Vector3 front = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 30) * center;
```

Проблема в том, что это работает когда `point` равен или близок `Vector3.up`.
По мере отклонения от вертикального положения боковые вектора начинают "слипаться".

Вот визуализация того, что мне нужно:

[image: Визуализация векторов]

Тестовый код и даже [ссылка на тестовую сцену](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yAc5vuX07tVANNhwj-9x08DDVvmoX31v) прилагаются.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject centerGO;
    public GameObject leftGO;
    public GameObject rightGO;
    public GameObject backGO;
    public GameObject frontGO;

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    void Start()
    {
        SetCenterPoint(Vector3.up);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        DrawDebugRays();

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            SetCenterPoint(hit.point);
        }
    }

    void SetCenterPoint(Vector3 point)
    {
        Vector3 center = point;
        Vector3 left = Quaternion.Euler(-30, 0, 0) * center;
        Vector3 right = Quaternion.Euler(30, 0, 0) * center;
        Vector3 back = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -30) * center;
        Vector3 front = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 30) * center;

        centerGO.transform.position = center;
        leftGO.transform.position = left;
        rightGO.transform.position = right;
        backGO.transform.position = back;
        frontGO.transform.position = front;

        list.Clear();
        list.Add(center);
        list.Add(left);
        list.Add(right);
        list.Add(front);
        list.Add(back);
    }

    void DrawDebugRays()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Color color = Color.red;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    color = Color.green;
                    break;
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    color = Color.blue;
                    break;
            }
            Debug.DrawRay(Vector3.zero, (Vector3)list[i], color);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Координаты точки *center* указаны в локальных или мировых координатах? Квартернионы вращают строго вокруг начала координат.

Comment: В данном случае центр centr'a находится в позиции (0,0,0)(т.е в начале координат) и вектор всегда нормализован

Comment: Vector3 left = Quaternion.Euler(-30, 0, 0) * center; мож из-за того, что вычисленный кватернион потом умножается на vector3 (всё смешали в одну кучу)? Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 30, 0).

Comment: @Ziens, Попробуйте посмотреть статью https://habrahabr.ru/post/183908/. Возможно, поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Помогли решить вопрос на gamedev.se.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/155322/unity3d-rotate-vector-by-n-degrees/155341#155341

Умножение кватернионов следует изменить следующим образом:

```
Quaternion localSpace = Quaternion.LookRotation(center);

Vector3 back = localSpace * Quaternion.Euler(-30, 0, 0) * Vector3.forward;
Vector3 front = localSpace * Quaternion.Euler(30, 0, 0) * Vector3.forward;
Vector3 right = localSpace * Quaternion.Euler(0, -30, 0) * Vector3.forward;
Vector3 left = localSpace * Quaternion.Euler(0, 30, 0) * Vector3.forward;
```